# Symfony 2 Doctrine COUNT

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

I have in my table "Artiste" one column "valideAdmin" who takes value 1 or 0.

I try to make a simple count to return the number of entries in my table where "valideAdmin" is to 1:

```
    $repo = $this   ->getDoctrine()
                    ->getManager()
                    ->getRepository('ProjectMainBundle:Artiste');

    $qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('valideAdmin');
    $qb->select('COUNT(valideAdmin)');
    $qb->where('valideAdmin=1');

    $count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();

    return array(
        'count' => $count
    );
```

But it always "1" who's return...

Without where clause, I have the total count of the entries of the table, but valideAdmin can be 0 or 1. I only want the count number where valideAdmin=1

Thanks for help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`createQueryBuilder()`'s first parameter is the `alias` that you want your entity to take (ie.: a short name to be used to refer to your entity in the query).

What you need to do is set a proper alias for your entity (for example `a` for `Artiste`) and then `COUNT()` the instances of your entity where the **property** (not the column) `valideAdmin` is set to one:

```
$repo = $this   ->getDoctrine()
                ->getManager()
                ->getRepository('ProjectMainBundle:Artiste');

$qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('a');
$qb->select('COUNT(a)');
$qb->where('a.valideAdmin = :valideAdmin');
$qb->setParameter('valideAdmin', 1);

$count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Remember that `DQL` runs queries on **entities**. The `DQL` your write is then translated into `SQL` to query the underlying data source after.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can fetch all date then use of **COUNT** function in **PHP**
This method has an advantage.You do not have to use a complex query.
You have all the information with count columns

```
$repositoryArtiste = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('ProjectMainBundle:Artiste');
        $queryArtiste=   $repositoryArtiste->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->Where('a.valideAdmin = :valideAdmin')
            ->setParameter('valideAdmin',1)
            ->getQuery();
        $Artiste = $queryArtiste->getResult();
        var_dump(count($Artiste));
```